# php extension "PCNTL" is suitable for a web spider?

Tags: php, web-crawler, php-extension, pcntl

Recently I try to write a web spider, so I find some projects about web spider written in PHP.

In those projects, I found the extension "PCNTL" is used frequently, but I can't find any detail tutorials or manuals about it.

So I want to know if extension "PCNTL" is really suitable for a web spider? If not, what are the alternatives.

Comment: voting to close.. This is not a real question.

Comment: Question is good, but the way is asked is not very good. I did edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PCNTL" is extensions with C-like process related functions, most notably `fork`.

I am not sure if there are good tutorials, but you can check C / C++ examples in order to understand how to use those PHP functions.

Several years ago we did web crawler. Instead of `fork`, we have used a shell script that started 100 instances of the crawler in parallel.

Another alternative is `curl-multi`, but once again there is no enough information and tutorials for it. We tried it and we do not found it very reliable, but I believe you should check it.

Another alternative is to do it in Python - there are several different program libraries that gives a lot of possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your response and edit，I will try it what you mentioned in anwer, maybe PHP is not the best way for spider, I will then continue study it.
In addition, this is my first question on this platform, and my English is very poor, I will keep practising.
Anyway thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Check my answer here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/326290/most-efficient-time-cost-way-to-scrape-5-million-web-pages/538958